# Default 403 page not showing up

Tags: html, .htaccess

I recently set up a few new folders in my server, but I wanted to turn them and all their subfolders forbidden. So, using `.htaccess`, I simply used `deny from all`. The issue here is that it's redirecting me to my host's 404 page (which has a lot of advertisements, join us, it looks like their front page), instead of the regular 403 page.

This seems like a very trivial question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. How do I get everything in that folder to use the classic 403 page, being this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /example/example2/exampleC/
on this server.</p>
</head>
</html>
```

Which changes depending on which folder I just entered. If In `/example/` I have `/example1/`, `/example2/` and `/example3/`, how do I make it so that if I enter /example1/, I get a 403 page that says I don't have access to `/example/example1/`?

This may seem a bit overly (needlessly) complicated.

Comment: >>I get a 403 page that says I don't have .... it sounds like your .htaccess file is not involved / exec by the server. Please check if you are able to use .htaccess by your ISP and could you please post your .htaccess (the relevant) code

Comment: I'm a hundred percent sure that .htaccess is working on my server, for I've used it for a lot of things (cookies, removal of indexes, redirects, errordocuments, etc). If I specify an ErrorDocument, yes, that document loads up. But if I don't specify an ErrorDocument, then my webhost (http://error404.000webhost.com/)'s 404 shows up instead (regardless of the error code).

Comment: And there's nothing in the .htaccess inside the folders besides

    deny from all

Comment: >>If I specify an ErrorDocument, yes, that document loads up. But if I don't specify an ErrorDocument, then my webhost 404 shows up instead<< Sounds like a wrong configuration of the server ... one question, have you a root .htaccess with rewrite rules, if yes, can you post it? next thing, can you for debugging insert in one subfolder a .htaccess with the content RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.de [L,R=301] [When you redirect to google htacess works and the problem must be somewhere else ...

Comment: I can't say it fits in this comment section, so here it is in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cQwzMBkm

  I put that in my .htaccess, but it didn't successfully redirect to google, it just sent it to: http://www.(my domain).net/www/www.(my domain).net/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4(deny from all in here)/folder5(.htaccess in here)/google.de

Comment: And I had to remove the deny from all from folder4, else folder5 was still redirecting to 00webhost's 404 page.

Comment: old and bit offtopic, but the body is not closed properly, there is closing head tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

let's debug step by step

for debugging please follow these steps

1. Rename in your DocumentRoot .htaccess to .htaccess_safe
2. Create a folder in DocumentRoot "test"
3. Insert in that folder a **.htaccess** with following content

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.de [L,R=301]
4. Open in your Browser http://example.com/test/   [you should redirect to google]

If this works ... read more under step 5.

If not ... put this .htaccess in the DocumentRoot Folder and open in your Browser http://example.com/test/ if this doesn't run too, stop debugging. If it works, your Server isn't able to exec .htaccess in subfolders (check for that the rights of the .htaccess file on your server group, user and chmod .....

(5) Rename your .htaccess_safe back to .htaccess and change line 12 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.avatarchan.net/site/ [R=301,L] to #RewriteRule ^$ http://www.avatarchan.net/site/ [R=301,L] and try again

Comment: The rewrite engine worked, but adding a hash before 'RewriteRule' didn't affect the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will tomorrow take a look at it, maybe another user can help you today

Comment: .... one more to try: adding all lines with hashes and try if this success, try to uncomment the first block ... and try ... and post the result of your tries

Comment: No luck even if I turn every line into a comment. I'll contact 00webhost, perhaps it's some strange configuration of theirs. Though I doubt it.